# Priorities in Priority Queue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, collections, queue, priority-queue

I was doing interview question on priority queues and have a simple question I was hoping to get some help with. The question is:

Should the priorities be integral? Could I implement string priorities.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?

The priorities can be anything that have a partial order defined, although a total order would be more common (e.g. integers, or strings ordered lexiographically).

Comment: Are you certain that partial order is enough? That it does not have to be total?

Comment: @JanHudec the heap property is that an object in the heap precedes in the order the two objects beneath it in the heap; as long as that property holds all the time the heap is going to fine. If you end up with a situation where there are non-comparable objects in the heap one beneath another then the heap is no longer well defined.

Comment: So what does guarantee that you don't end up with two non-comparable objects beneath one another?

Comment: (I am pretty certain that nothing. All the heap structures usually defined in textbooks assume weak total order. It is possible to define a heap for partially ordered objects, but I've not seen it anywhere and it won't have as good complexity)

Comment: Nothing guarantees it. A heap obviously enforces a linear order, because the objects are popped out of it in a specific (linear) order. But one could e.g. envision a heap where when there are two non-comparable siblings and one has to be promoted (during "percolate up"), one would choose randomly. I think the heap would still work logically correctly, i.e. would never pop from the top an object that would be preceded by any other object in the heap.

Comment: I suspect you confuse partial and weak ordering. In weak ordering, the "incomparable" elements form equivalence classes and you can treat them as equal for this purpose. But partial ordering can have element incomparable with multiple elements that between them are comparable, so whenever new element enters such queue, it must be compared with _all_ currently minimal elements to find where to put it.

Comment: I've recently [discussed priority queues to great extent (and without conclusive result)](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/priority-queue-for-partially-ordered-priorities).

Comment: @JanHudec I meant partial ordering, not weak ordering. But I haven't thought this through :D