# Grading partial orders (starting from topological sort)

Tags: haskell, topological-sort, partial-ordering

This blog post discusses an interesting variation on topological sort: http://jdh.hamkins.org/linear-gradings-of-partial-orders/

A linear grading of a partial order is just like a topological sort, except that, where permissible, vertices can share a "level" in the output.

How would one implement a program (in Haskell, say) to find all of the linear gradings of a partial order (i.e. a DAG)?

In the case of the illustration in the blog post, a topological sort can easily find the ordering [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5]]. Then the Haskell program

```
map concat $ sequence $ map concat $ map (map permutations) $ map partitions [[1],[2,3,4],[5]]
```

seems to produce the right result. I think this code doesn't correctly solve the general case, though.

Comment: I don't want to write out the code, so I'm not making this an answer, but... a naive solution would be to maintain a seen set (the set of nodes which have already appeared in the linear grading) and a frontier set (the set of nodes which is "available" because all its predecessors are in the seen set). At each step, you nondeterministically choose from the power set of the frontier as the next level in the linear grading, then update your seen and frontier sets appropriately. Afterwards, you could consider trying dynamic programming so that the tails of `[1]:[2]:_` and `[2]:[1]:_` are shared.

Comment: I looked into the literature on trace theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_monoid) to see if there was anything there that might help. Maybe the concept of an independency relation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_relation.

Comment: An “extra” level just selects a subset of the permutations, where some elements are fixed to particular positions, no? `[[a], [b, c]]` yields the subsets of the permutations of `[a, b, c]` in which `a` comes first. You could save a lot of work on the shared subproblems, though, e.g. between that and `[[b, c], [a]]`. Also a toposort does *not* automatically give you the minimum number of levels. I don’t know offhand if that’s equivalent to finding the maximum width of the partial order, but if so, [that can be done in polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem).

Comment: Kahn's algorithm for topological sort can be made to output the minimum number of levels, AFAICS. As Wikipedia says, and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hit-graph-0.1/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Query-Topsort.html too, "The internals of structure S, the set of nodes with no inbound edges, aren't specified. Therefore, so is the order in which nodes are removed from it." I'm not saying we have to start with a topological sort, though! Of course, maybe I'm misunderstanding something about the behaviour of Kahn's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments received so far, here is a sketch of what an answer might look like.

This code computes ordered partitions of a list. With a suitable poset data structure, `avail` and `update` could be replaced with appropriate functions, and I think the logic would hold.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

delems xs zs = foldr delete zs xs
powerset xs = filterM (\x -> [True, False]) xs

-- returns the currently available subsets
avail s = filter (not . null) $ powerset s

-- updates the data structure
update e s = delems e s

ordered_partitions [] = [[]]
ordered_partitions set = do
  elems <- avail set
  remainder <- ordered_partitions (update elems set)
  [elems:remainder]
```

It seems that heaps (priority queues) for posets aren't a widely implemented thing. There is some discussion here [Priorities in Priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988645/priorities-in-priority-queue) and here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/priority-queue-for-partially-ordered-priorities-with-infima. Particularly relevant is the distinction between weak orderings and partial orders. Weak orders are much easier to handle.

Kahn's algorithm seems promising as a way of implementing this priority queue...